# useMemo vs. useEffect + useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Are there any benefits in using `useMemo` (e.g. for an intensive function call) instead of using a combination of `useEffect` and `useState`?

Here are two custom hooks that work exactly the same on first sight, besides `useMemo`'s return value being `null` on the first render:

[image: See on CodeSandbox]

#### useEffect & useState

```tsx
import { expensiveCalculation } from "foo";

function useCalculate(someNumber: number): number | null {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<number | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setResult(expensiveCalculation(someNumber));
  }, [someNumber]);

  return result;
}
```

#### useMemo

```tsx
import { expensiveCalculation } from "foo";

function useCalculateWithMemo(someNumber: number): number {
    return useMemo(() => {
        return expensiveCalculation(someNumber);
    }, [someNumber]);
};
```

Both calculate the result each time their parameter `someNumber` changes, where is the memoization of `useMemo` kicking in?

Comment: The first will be `null` on the first render, while the second won't?

Comment: *Are there any benefits in using useMemo (e. g. for an intensive function call)* - yes. You're using a hook that was designed specifically for this purpose. The example you listed is most common real world example for useMemo.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The `useEffect` and `setState` will cause extra renders on every change: the first render will "lag behind" with stale data and then it'll immediately queue up an additional render with the new data.

---

Suppose we have:

```
// Maybe I'm running this on a literal potato
function expensiveCalculation(x) { return x + 1; };
```

Lets suppose `x` is initially 0:

- The `useMemo` version immediately renders `1`.
- The `useEffect` version renders `null`, then after the component renders the effect runs, changes the state, and queues up a new render with `1`.

Then if we change `x` to 2:

- The `useMemo` runs and `3` is rendered.
- The `useEffect` version runs, and renders `1` again, then the effect triggers and the component reruns with the correct value of `3`.

In terms of how often `expensiveCalculation` runs, the two have identical behavior, but the `useEffect` version is causing twice as much rendering which is bad for performance for other reasons.

Plus, the `useMemo` version is just cleaner and more readable, IMO.  It doesn't introduce unnecessary mutable state and has fewer moving parts.

So you're better off just using `useMemo` here.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced if this rule would apply to every scenario. I'd like to know and try what would happen if it really was an expensive calc or if it was a network call where you might want to do two renders, one with a spinner and one with the final value. I guess that's what the new Suspense features are all about and perhaps they work fine with useMemo

I did try a version, but it doesn't tell me much so I think it needs some rework

https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo-vs-useeffect-usestate-ye6qm

Comment: @MarkAdamson It applies to every scenario in which you are using `useEffect` to synchronously compute a value and setting it with `useState`.  It doesn't apply for asynchronous situations like where you'd want to show a loading spinner.

Comment: I think the useEffect could be useful in some long running synchronous scenarios too.

Check out the sandbox below. It takes 5 seconds to load because of the useMemo holding the render thread while the long calc runs, while the useEffect/useState one can show a 'spinner' while the calc is running so doesn't hold up the render:
https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo-vs-useeffect-usestate-ye6qm

@Retsam

Comment: besides  optimization, I use `useMemo` instead of the `useState` + `useEffect` pattern because debugging is harder with more renders.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the React API docs mention that `useMemo` doesn’t guarantee that the memoized function won’t be executed again if the dependencies don’t change because React may, in the future, discard cache to improve performance. So if the memoized function has side effects of some kind, it might be smarter to use a custom hook.

Comment: Why will it render "1" again when the numberProp changes to 2

Comment: @Abhi Changing a prop triggers a re-render.  But the value that is rendered is based on the `[result, setResult]` state, and `setResult` won't be called until the `useEffect` runs, which happens *after* the render.

Comment: `useState` can recieve a function to calculate its initial value. So, if there is no need in recalculating memoized value based on props, then `useState` and `useMemo` are equal?  
`const [x] = useState(() => calcX())` is equivalent to `const x = useMemo(() => calcX(), [])`?

Comment: @DmitryDavydov I think that's true, but if the `calcX()` calculation doesn't depend on any state or props of your component, you can pull it out the component as a constant and don't need to use a hook at all.

Comment: Can we conclude from this that `useEffect` + `useState` is the right solution in situations where the thing to compute is `async`, because the value cannot be available in the current render anyway? Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61751728/1804173).

Comment: @bluenote10 Yeah, it doesn't generally make sense to memoize the promise itself, so you'd instead want to update state based on the result of the promise.

Comment: I see as wrote from other above that useMemo suite way better case when there are exteremely expensive calculation that do not depend on states or any side effects, so more for pure "funcions" case

Comment: @MarkAdamson quite the opposite, is better use useEffect + useState when there is a need of an async code that it's by nature a side effects, meaning his happening outside and you don't know exactly when, as here others have already pointed out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751728/asynchronous-calls-with-react-usememo

Comment: Thanks @CarmineTambascia, it's been a while since I posted that so don't recall the context. But I don't think our statements are contradictory. I was identifying a time when useEffect could be useful for synchronous actions that don't have side effects vs. usememo. It's still the case that useEffect is intended  and designed for helping with side effects as you say.

Comment: "In terms of how often expensiveCalculation runs, the two have identical behavior" - not necessarily. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67131354/5134722). "useEffect guarantees that it will not be fired if dependencies have not changed. useMemo does not give such guarantees." So there is a semantic difference. useMemo is allowed to run the expensive calc more than once even if the dependencies didn't change.

Answer (score 29):

I think there are two main points you should consider when choosing between them.

1. Time when function called.

`useEffect` called after component has been rendered, so you can access DOM from it. For example, this is important if you want to access DOM elements via refs.

2. Semantic guarantees.

`useEffect` guarantees that it will not be fired if dependencies have not changed. `useMemo` does not give such guarantees.

As stated in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), you should consider useMemo as pure optimization technique. Your program should continue to work correctly even if you replace useMemo with regular function call.

`useEffect` + `useState` can be used to control updates. Even to break-up circular dependencies and prevent infinite update loops.

Comment: useEffect does NOT warranty that it will not re-render when dependencies have not changed. useMemo is the one that does not fire when dependencies have not changed. I have never had issue of extra re-renders on useMemo, contrary to useEffect that sometimes re-renders when dependencies have not changed. Instead, you want to watch out for the fact that useMemo struggles to detect some changes in some dependencies that are complex in structure. (for example, a change in an object that is inside of an array).

Answer (score 20):

I would say other than the async nature, there might be some difference in terms how they are designed.

`useEffect` is a collective call, async or not, it's collected after all components are rendered.

`useMemo` is a local call, which has only something to do with this component. You could just think of `useMemo` as another assignment statement with benefits to use the assignment from last update.

This means, `useMemo` is more urgent, and then `useLayoutEffect` and the last being `useEffect`.