# Use case for useLayoutEffect + useState vs useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've seen this answer: [useMemo vs. useEffect + useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028913/usememo-vs-useeffect-usestate) , and it sums it up well for `useEffect`, but in my case I want to perform an expensive operation that will change the DOM as early as possible. Would `useMemo()` still be recommended instead of `useLayoutEffect()` with a state update? Does the double render of effect -> state-update negate any performance boost?

**EDIT**

`useLayoutEffect()` scenario:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const tokens = expensiveOperationGeneratingClasses(param1)
    setTokens(tokens)
}, 
[param1])

 render (
  <>
   {
       tokens.map(token => <span className={token.id}/>)
   }
  </>
 )
```

`useMemo` scenario:

```
const tokens = useMemo(() => {
     return expensiveOperationGeneratingClasses(param1)
},
[param1]

 render (
  <>
   {
       tokens.map(token => <span className={token.id}/>)
   }
  </>
 )
```

Actually I realised that I'm not doing DOM operations but rather just generating the class names before the rendering of the `<span>` tags to avoid flickering, so I think i'm better off using `useMemo`, am I right?

Comment: And what specific operation do you want to perform?

Comment: I want to change the class names of `<span>` tags after doing lots of RegEx operations on the text.

Comment: Please bring examples for  a better understanding.

Comment: @PFuster are your calculations related to props?

Comment: Yes sorry the param1 is a prop

Comment: @PFuster Yes you are right. Use useMemo.

Comment: @RichWarrior if you want to write an answer I'll be happy to accept it. If  somebody can clear up the timing of when useMemo vs useLayoutEffect are fired concerning the rendering that would be perfect.

Comment: @PFuster I am looking  for a  satisfying answer for you but still there is no result.Nobody  gives a certain  answer for your question. If I manage to find satisfying answer i will inform you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to explain where you can use LayoutEffect and Memo. Let's start with the using of LayoutEffect.

The using of LayoutEffect has some drawbacks says Dan Abramov [Link 1](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1096916868026245121), [Link 2](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1056476921347932161).It's a good explanation of where you can use these gives [Kent C](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect). Dodds.If you need an example, you can see it here [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005663/when-to-use-useimperativehandle-uselayouteffect-and-usedebugvalue). Don't forget about reading for understand the difference.

Now about of the using Memo. It's also has a [drawback](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1085685515951714306). For what we use Memo ,and where it is used you can found [here](https://usehooks.com/useMemo/).

And now in practice.

option 1 use LayoutEffect

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
const Control = () => {
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <PostOffice add={add} />
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => setAdd(add + 1)}>{"Click"}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function PostOffice({ add }) {
  const [letter, setLetter] = useState(add);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("useLayoutEffect");
    setLetter(add);
  }, [add]);

  console.log(letter);
  return <div className="App">{console.log(letter, "DOM")}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Control />, rootElement);
```

I'm not sure about this option 1, because there is an [anti-pattern effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props) here.

option 2 use LayoutEffect

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
const Control = () => {
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <PostOffice add={add} />
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => setAdd(add + 1)}>{"Click"}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function PostOffice({ add }) {
  const [letter, setLetter] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("useLayoutEffect");
    setLetter(add);
  }, [add]);

  console.log(letter);
  return <div className="App">{console.log(letter, "DOM")}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Control />, rootElement);
```

there will be a meaningless rendering

option useMemo

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
const Control = () => {
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <PostOffice add={add} />
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => setAdd(add + 1)}>{"Click"}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function PostOffice({ add }) {
  const Letter = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("useMemo");
    return add + 1;
  }, [add]);

  console.log(Letter);
  return <div className="App">{console.log(Letter, "DOM")}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Control />, rootElement);
```

And here everything works perfectly

Total

Minus useMemo [1](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1085685515951714306),

Minus useLayoutEffect, [1](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1096916868026245121),anti-pattern effect or meaningless rendering,adding useState,

This is why you should use useMemo.

but if there is a way not to use these hooks, it will be perfect.