# Asynchronous calls with React.useMemo

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-usememo

Scenario is relatively simple: we have a long-running, on-demand calculation that occurs on a remote server. We want to memoize the result. Even though we are fetching asychronously from a remote resource, this isn't a side effect because we just want the result of this calculation to display to the user and we definitely don't want to do this on every render.

Problem: it seems that React.useMemo does not directly support Typescript's async/await and will return a promise:

```
//returns a promise: 
let myMemoizedResult = React.useMemo(() => myLongAsyncFunction(args), [args])
//also returns a promise:
let myMemoizedResult = React.useMemo(() => (async () => await myLongAsyncFunction(args)), [args])
```

What is the correct way to wait on the result from an asynchronous function and memoize the result using React.useMemo? I've used regular promises with plain JS but still struggle with them in these types of situations.

I've tried other approaches such as memoize-one, but the issue seems to be that the `this` context changes due to the way that React function components work [break the memoization](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one#changes-to-this-is-considered-an-argument-change), which is why I'm trying to use React.useMemo.

Maybe I'm trying to fit a square peg in a round hole here - if that's the case it would be good to know that too. For now I'm probably just going to roll my own memoizing function.

Edit: I think part of it was that I was making a different silly mistake with memoize-one, but I'm still interested to know the answer here wrt React.memo.

Here's a snippet - the idea is not to use the memoized result directly in the render method, but rather as something to reference in an event-driven way i.e. on a Calculate button click.

```
export const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
    let [arg, setArg] = React.useState('100');
    let [result, setResult] = React.useState('Not yet calculated');

    //My hang up at the moment is that myExpensiveResultObject is 
    //Promise<T> rather than T
    let myExpensiveResultObject = React.useMemo(
        async () => await SomeLongRunningApi(arg),
        [arg]
    );

    const getResult = () => {
        setResult(myExpensiveResultObject.interestingProperty);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Get your result:</p>
            <input value={arg} onChange={e => setArg(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button onClick={getResult}>Calculate</button>
            <p>{`Result is ${result}`}</p>
        </div>);
}
```

Comment: Why not `let myMemoizedResult = await React.useMemo(() => myLongAsyncFunction(args), [args])
`

Comment: @GazihanAlankus Wouldn't that just result in a memoized promise calling back to the long running asynchronous function every time, even if the args haven't changed?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about useMemo, I just thought you are having an issue with async/await in general. It seems they argue against what you are trying to do: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-usememo#when-not-to-usememo "You won’t want to have useMemo fire off any side effects or any asynchronous calls. Both of those would make more sense to be contained within useEffect."

Comment: Thanks for the response - this is why I included the part about this not being a side effect. 

useEffect checks the args on every render, which is not the desired behavior here because the user may want to change more than one input before calling the long running calculation..

Comment: Well the docs state that you must use useMemo as a performance optimization only. and *Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.* In the above case it sure does return a promise because the return type of function executed by usememo is a Promise as it uses async.

As of now react doesn't provide a way to execute apis and get result in render. With the introdution of suspense that soon will be possible. For now you can execute your apis in useEffect and update the state

Comment: I think I need to add more detail to the original question to make it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

What you really want is to re-render your component once the asynchronous call is over. Memoisation alone won't help you achieve that. Instead you should use React's state - it will keep the value your async call returned and it will allow you to trigger a re-render.

Furthermore, triggering an async call is a side effect, so it should not be performed during the render phase - neither inside the main body of the component function, nor inside `useMemo(...)` which also happens during the render phase. Instead all side effects should be triggered inside `useEffect`.

Here's the complete solution:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  let active = true
  load()
  return () => { active = false }

  async function load() {
    setResult(undefined) // this is optional
    const res = await someLongRunningApi(arg1, arg2)
    if (!active) { return }
    setResult(res)
  }
}, [arg1, arg2])
```

Here we call the async function inside `useEffect`. Note that you cannot make the whole callback inside `useEffect` async - that's why instead we declare an async function `load` inside and call it without awaiting.

The effect will re-run once one of the `arg`s changes - this is what you want in most cases. So make sure to memoise `arg`s if you re-calculate them on render. Doing `setResult(undefined)` is optional - you might instead want to keep the previous result on the screen until you get the next result. Or you might do something like `setLoading(true)` so the user knows what's going on.

Using `active` flag is important. Without it you are exposing yourself to a race condition waiting to happen: the second async function call may finish before the first one finishes:

1. start first call
2. start second call
3. second call finishes, `setResult()` happens
4. first call finishes, `setResult()` happens again, overwriting
   the correct result with a stale one

and your component ends up in an inconsistent state. We avoid that by using `useEffect`'s cleanup function to reset the `active` flag:

1. set `active#1 = true`, start first call
2. arg changes, cleanup function is called, set `active#1 = false`
3. set `active#2 = true`, start second call
4. second call finishes, `setResult()` happens
5. first call finishes, `setResult()` doesn't happen since `active#1` is `false`

Comment: How about reformatting this answer? Maybe `# Do this (good impl., comments if needed) # Watch out (bad example, with comments)`

Comment: Thanks for the invitation, though tapping edit, it says "Suggested edit queue is full" so either I'm somehow banned or limited from editing, or if it's this answer that has a full queue. Anyway I se you did some improvements :) Nice!

Comment: @SimonB. thanks. I finally completely rewrote the answer, hope it's better now

Comment: This should be the right answer for async. It works perfectly @SimonB.

Comment: It would work but won't be recommended. It is usually a bad idea to set states in a useEffect hook. Actually with your code you will as well have a react hooks exhaustive deps warn.

Answer (score 6):

I think React specifically mentions that [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) should not be used to manage side effects like asynchronous API calls. They should be managed in `useEffect` hooks where there are proper dependencies set to determine whether they should be re-run or not.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** My original answer below seems to have some unintended side effects due to the asynchronous nature of the call. I would instead try and either think about memoizing the actual computation on the server, or using a self-written closure to check if the `arg` hasn't changed. Otherwise you can still utilize something like `useEffect` as I described below.

I believe the problem is that `async` functions always implicitly return a promise. Since this is the case, you can directly `await` the result to unwrap the promise:

```
const getResult = async () => {
  const result = await myExpensiveResultObject;
  setResult(result.interestingProperty);
};
```

See an [example codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-kirch-2sb01?file=/src/App.tsx:550-716).

I do think though that a better pattern may be to utilize a `useEffect` that has a dependency on some state object that only gets set on the button click in this case, but it seems like the `useMemo` should work as well.