# Is useMemo asynchronous like useState Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

Usually we cannot use the state value of useSate immediately after setting it. Is it the same for useMemo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous calls with React.useMemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751728/asynchronous-calls-with-react-usememo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useMemo` is asynchronous if it depends on `asynchronous` values such as `useState`.

To explain this, let's check a demo component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1)
  const memoValue = useMemo(() => value + 1, [value])
  console.log('value is: ', value)
  console.log('memoValue is: ', memoValue)

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(10)
    console.log('effect value is: ', value)
    console.log('effect memoValue is: ', memoValue)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>test</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Its console output is:

```sh
value is:  1
memoValue is:  2
effect value is:  1
effect memoValue is:  2
value is:  10
memoValue is:  11
```

As you can see, after `setValue` in `useEffect`, `value` is old, so does `memoValue`.

Explain:

You can treat hooks as a function who re-executes when `state` or `props` changes. `useMemo` is just a memorized function.

`setValue` changes `App`'s state, marks App as a dirty component(need re-execute), but before `App` re-executes, `memoValue` has no way to update its value, so it is `asynchronous` in your definition.