# Axios call is in pending state and only finishes after my component completely renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a component which makes an axios call. The component is supposed to make an axios call to return data and then render that data, however, the data returns back undefined and I noticed the console log has the promise stuck in pending state and it only completes **after** the whole component is finished rendering. I used async and await so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

---

```
let panels = {documentSource: {summary: 'Document Source', content: new Set()},
  legalName: {summary: 'Legal Name', content: new Set()},};

const RenderData = () => {

  const [context] = useContext(Context);

  const getLegalName = async(id) => {
    CommonService()
    .getLegalNamesById([id])
    .then((response) => {
      const legal = response.data.results[0];
      return legal.name + ' - ' + legal.id;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  const fetchResults = async() => {
    for(let i = 0; i < context.length; i++) {
        panels.documentSource.content.add(context[i].documentSource[0]);
        panels.legalName.content.add(await getLegalName(context[i].legalName[0]));
    }
    return panels;
  };

  const callBackFetchResults = useMemo(() => fetchResults(), [context]);

  return (
      <Accordion
        panels={['documentSource', 'documentStatus', 'jpmcLegalEntityName', 'productName', 'documentTitle']}
        renderPanel={({ value, getPanelProps }) => {
              let panel = callBackFetchResults[value];
              let panelArr = Array.from(panel.content);
              return (
                <Checkbox label={item} key={item}  />
              );     
          }
       />
     );
      />
    </div>
  )};
```

Comment: Maybe u need to use useEffect function to rerender your composent When your request is done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the `fetchResults` invocation in the `useMemo` is not `await`ed. Based on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751728/asynchronous-calls-with-react-usememo) I'm not sure if `useMemo` supports async/await. Instead of `useMemo` you could store the result in state and use an effect to fetch the data, accompanied by loading state to prevent rendering until the data is available:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);

  fetchResults()
    .then((data) => {
      setResults(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      ...handle error...
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    })
}, []);

return (
  loading ? 'loading...' : <Accordian />
);
```

Comment: I tried this but it still only renders the data after the component is finished rendering