# Why useMemo as function that are in the useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (portfolios && portfolios.length > 0) {
  const wLocation = portfolios.filter((portfolio: Portfolios) =>
    portfolio.organizations.some(organization => organization.locations ?? false),
  );
  const wOutLocation = portfolios.filter((portfolio: Portfolios) =>
    portfolio.organizations.every(organization => organization.locations ?? true),
  );
  setPortfoliosWOutLocation(getItemsWRGB(wOutLocation.map(portfolioFormatted)));
  setPortfoliosWLocation(getItemsWRGB(wLocation.map(portfolioFormatted)));
}}, [portfolios]);
```

One of my partners tell me that I could use useMemo in order to avoid re calculation in every render, so I did this:

```
const portfolioWLocation = useMemo(() => {
const wLocation = portfolios.filter((portfolio: Portfolios) =>
    portfolio.organizations.some(organization => organization.locations ?? false),
  );
return getItemsWRGB(wLocation.map(portfolioFormatted));}, [portfolios]);

const portfolioWOutLocation = useMemo(() => {
const wOutLocation = portfolios.filter((portfolio: Portfolios) =>
    portfolio.organizations.every(organization => organization.locations ?? true),
  );
return getItemsWRGB(wOutLocation.map(portfolioFormatted));}, [portfolios]);
```

Will not be the same since `portfolios` is the dependency for `useMemo()` and `useEffect()`.

Comment: Hi José, and welcome to SO! Can you please clarify what the question is?

Comment: hey @YoavKadosh, I just want to know if there are any real difference to have the `useMemo` or do that calculation into the `useEffect` do you follow me ?

Comment: I found the solutions on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028913/usememo-vs-useeffect-usestate

Comment: OK, i'm glad you did. I also answered your question, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of performance, there is no difference between the two. Both will only be executed if at least one of their dependencies has changed.

But they each serve a different purpose.

`useMemo()` is used for memoizing a value that can later be used within the component, while `useEffect()` is used for performing side effects (usually for doing some DOM manipulations or updating the state).

In your case, it seems like you are trying to compute some value, so you should use `useMemo()`.

If you use `useEffect()`, you will have to maintain a state with `useState()`, and this will indeed have a negative impact on the performance since it will trigger additional renders.