# Is useMemo usefull rendering a prop value?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks

What's the difference between those two patterns ? Is the `useMemo` usefull ?

Will the number of rerenders change ?

### 1 - Just rendering a modified prop

```
const Component = ({ myObject }) => {
  const computedValue = changeMyValueWithSomeCalculus(myObject.value)
  return (
    <div>
       {computedValue}
    </div>
  )
};
```

### 2 - Using useMemo

```
const Component = ({ myObject }) => {
  const computedValue = useMemo(() => {
    return changeMyValueWithSomeCalculus(myObject.value);
  }, [myObject.value]);

  return (
    <div>
       {computedValue}
    </div>
  )
};
```

I've ran into this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028913/usememo-vs-useeffect-usestate) very instructive but doesn't help me out with this choice !

Comment: Depends on if the called function is time-intensive and how often the dependency changes.

Comment: In the case number `1` if I have another prop calculated but only the second one updates then both will be calculated again ... And it's not the case in the second pattern right ?

Comment: But what does it change with a time consuming calculus when there's only a unique variable rendered ?

Comment: useMemo will not change the number of times the component renders. What it changes is the number of times `changeMyValueWithSomeCalculus` gets run. Option 1 runs it on every render. Option 2 runs it only if myObject.value changed. So if that's an expensive function, and myObject.value rarely changes, useMemo can improve performance.