# Dropdown item select triggers data processing - delay in closing dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown created with MUI [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/), [MenuItem](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item/), and [FormControl](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control/).

The `Select`'s `onChange` updates a state variable using `useState`'s callback function:

```
const handleDropdownChange = (e) => setDropdownVariable(e.target.value)
```

The state variable is a `useMemo` dependency (one of several dependencies, simplified below):

```
const result = useMemo(() => expensiveCalculation(), [dropdownStateVariable])
```

Everything works as intended.

**Problem:** The dropdown does not close until `expensiveCalculation` has finished running. The delay is only 1-2 seconds at the most, but ideally I'd like to close the dropdown before/while the process is running.

`expensiveCalculation` is not fetching data, but processing it. The data-fetching is done before this point, within `useEffect`.

I've chosen `useMemo` for this because I anticipate the user may frequently switch between different values of `dropdownStateVariable` and would like to benefit from the performance optimization of using memoized results.

Based on some preliminary research and some of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029184/3558874) I've seen, it seems like `useMemo` would be the correct choice for me. In that case, is there any way around the slight delay in closing the `Select` dropdown? On the other hand, using `useEffect`, I would be able to use a state loading variable to give immediate feedback that the request is being processed while asynchronously preparing the data - but I'd lose the benefit of memoization.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: JS runs on a single thread meaning if you click something in your list to close it BUT when you click it it also has to do that expensive calculations - then it will only close/rerender after its threat is empty (everything is done). You might be able to overcome this issue with async (promise) function so split it up. But my concern is - why you running and expensive calculations every time something happens to the dropdown and maybe the expensive calculations can be improved too to help this issue?

Comment: @Lith The dropdown is to change data being displayed. Async with useMemo is an issue

Comment: hmh.. if you are using a dropdown that on press calculates something and changes the display of the content then why not remove the logic from onclick into something like useeffect? onClick you set the state to something new and close the dropdown (no logic there, simple and fast to execute) then on useEffect to listen to new state of whatever user clicked and then runs the expensive calculations and rerenders once done. In the mean time you might display a loader to indicate a user that something is happening (loading) in the display. IMO that would solve ur issue and be better UE